# TableViewController scrolls under status bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, statusbar

I’m working on a project in Xcode 9.1 and a very strange problem occurs with my Table View Controller.

I need to have a table view with static cells and Xcode tells me that I can achieve this only with a TableViewController (doesn’t work with a TableView in a ViewController. Gives me errors).

I’ve embedded my TableViewController inside a Navigation Controller, but when I run the project, the table View scrolls and it’s visible under the status bar (on every iPhone, from X to SE).

I wanted to make the status bar opaque but didn’t find a way to do it.
Am I doing something wrong?

My steps are:

1) Dragged a TableViewController on the storyboard

2) Embed the TableViewController into a Navigation Bar (I’ve tried also to drag the Navigation Bar directly and it comes already connected to a TableViewController).

3) Set the Cells to Static

4) Run on device or simulator.

[Screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Goilg.jpg)

Comment: Try to set  the property "Extend Edges Under Top Bars" in the AttributeInspector to false. The property is on your TableViewController in the storyboard

Comment: Are you sure those four steps are all you've done? Create a new Xcode project, follow those four steps and the status bar and navigation bar should be opaque. The table view should begin below the navigation bar. Also, I assume in step 2, you meant to say "Embed the TableViewController into a Navigation Controller" ?

Comment: @CraigGrummitt yes, I’m sorry, I meant Navigation Controller. Just edited the question. And yes, I’ve done those steps again now, and I still have the tableview scrolling over the status bar

Comment: @TMob if I set it to false, my status bar and Navbars becomes black

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of "the tableview scrolling over the status bar"? Or a link to a github repo with the problem? Because following those steps I don't see the problem.

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of my problem to the original question. Thank you for your time @CraigGrummitt

Comment: Wow that is extraordinary and intriguing! I'm curious to download your project to diagnose the problem. Are you able to post a link to a github repo?

Comment: @Moritz I’m sorry. Still have to understand how stackoverflow works. Thank you for the advice

Comment: @Mehdi_Mahdloo No problem. It takes some time to get used to how it works here. I've edited your question to make it better.

Comment: @Moritz thank you again! Won’t make that mistake again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it!

The problem was the code I wrote to hide the navigation bar hairline (the 1px line under the bar).
Commenting the code make everything work fine.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your issue I think your Navigation Bar is set to hidden.

1. In your storyboard click on the navigationBar in the navigation controller.

2. Then look for the attributes section "Drawing"

3. Check to see if hidden is true.

4. If it is uncheck it.
My setup has it set to false as default.

to hide navigation you need to write below code in viewDidLoad

self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true

Comment: Unfortunately my navbar is not hidden :(

Comment: I just saw your screen shot. Have you tried running it on any other device? iPhone SE, 6, 6S, 7, real device etc? It may be a safe area issue.

Comment: Solved it! The problem was the code I wrote to make the navbar hairline disappear. Commenting the code made everything work fine!